# Error Code: 1318. Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to validate login data entered into a simple html form using Flask and MySQL.

When I post the request I get the following error:

`Error Code: 1318. Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE student.new_procedure; expected 1, got 4`

Here is my html form:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Ramster</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/index.css">
    <script src="/static/js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/validateLogin.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, height=100%">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="showLogin">Login</a>
        <a href="showRegister">Register</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <h2>Ramster</h2>
        <p>Register your team</p>
        <form class="example" action="/validateLogin" method="post" style="margin:left;max-width:600px">
        <input type="text" name="inputUsername" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username" required autofocus><br><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required><br><br><br>
        <button id="btnLogin" class="example" type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Terms and Conditions</p>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my python snippet:

```
@app.route('/validateLogin', methods=['POST'])
def validateLogin():
     # read the posted values from the UI
    try:
        _username = request.form['inputUsername']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']

     # validate the received values
        if _username and _password:

            with closing(mysql.connect()) as conn:
                #_hashed_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
                cursor.callproc('sp_validateLogin', (_username))
                data = cursor.fetchall()

                if len(data) > 0:
                    if check_password_hash(str(data[0][3]), _password):
                        session['user'] = data[0][0]
                        return redirect('/home')
                    else:
                        return render_template('error.html', error='Wrong Email address or Password.')
                else:
                    return render_template('error.html', error='Wrong Email address or Password.')

        else:
            return json.dumps({'html': '<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})

    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'error': str(e)})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

and here is my stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_validateLogin`(
IN _username VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
    select * from teams where username = _username;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm sure I'm getting something wrong with the check password portion, but I'm pretty new to this, and would appreciate some help

Comment: Correction: The error code was actually:

Comment: Actual error: Error Code: 1318. Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE RamsterDB.sp_validateLogin; expected 1, got 4